# Two nginx server blocks on same port

Tags: nginx

I need:

- Two web services which should be served on the same port (80).
- One service should only be served to localhost.

The server configs (two separate files, included in this order) are:

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:80;

    location /app {
        index index.html;
        alias /var/www/app;
    }
}

server {
    listen *:80 default_server;

    location /static {
        alias /var/www/static;
    }
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /path/to/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

**Problem:** The first server works but for requests intended to be handled the second server, I get 404.

- I tried [`bind`](https://nginx.org/r/listen) on the `listen` directive in both server blocks separately which causes the error "port already in use".

**Solutions / Work-arounds:**

- Use different port for the first server (o.k. because the only client is on localhost).

Comment: Why haven't you set a `server_name` in either block?

Comment: The device running the webserver is addressed by IP address. It does not have a public name. In the `127.0.0.1:80` case the server name could maybe be `localhost` but wouldn't it then get _all_ requests on address/port from `localhost`?

Answer (score 1):

In my point of View, it does not make sense to use 2 Blocks, if you want /app only accessible from 127.0.0.1 you can use allow to restrict it and use only one Block to serve it all, as I understand it correctly your request since its generic.

```
Server {
    listen *:80 default_server;
    location /app {
        index index.html;
        alias /var/www/app;
        allow 127.0.0.1
        deny all
    }
    location /static {
        alias /var/www/static;
    }
    location / {
         include     /path/to/uwsgi_params;
       uwsgi_pass  django;
    }
}
```

Since I don't have much Information, where "django" should be defined, I keep this as a generic solution for your currently generic question.

Comment: Thanks @djdomi, looks good. I wasn't aware of `allow` and `deny`. The only downside with one server block is that different services cannot manage their own nginx config in separate files. The configs must be merged into one server block.

Comment: that's what I did as you ask, else keep your question updated and more precisely ;) however you may alsu use include to nginx as debian do it that way and use server blocks in separate files.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t do two server blocks. Either have multiple IPs or use location directives

Comment: Do you mean specific IP addresses instead of `*:80`? The requirement is that one service is only accessible from localhost, the other service from *.

Answer (score -1):

Specify the IP in both blocks I.e 127.0.0.1 for the local one and 89.89.89.89 for example for the non-local host one.

You used *:80 in the second one which includes 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Thanks. But the server obtains the IP address automatically, and also, the second service should also be accessible from localhost, too.

Comment: That’s not how it works.

Comment: You can’t have it both ways... unless you use one on alternative port

Comment: Or use SNI by setting server_name however not sure that would work for this situation either